# Reading a CSV file using VBScript

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I have a file with 4 fields.

```
A,B,C,D
```

I want to only extract the 4th Field and change it to "E"

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Are the fields fixed length or variable length?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that the values don't contain commas, read in the file using [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (FSO), then [Split](http://w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp) each line on commas. Change the resulting array of 4 values as needed, then [join](http://w3schools.com/vbscript/func_join.asp) it together as a comma separated string again. When you've done all the changes, write the data back out to a file using FSO.

So something like:

```
Set outputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName1, ForWriting, True)
Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName2, ForReading)
Do While inputFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    arr = Split(inputFile.ReadLine, ",")
    arr(3) = "E"
    outputString = Join(arr, ",")
    outputFile.WriteLine outputString
Loop
```

Please note, the code is completely untested and written mostly from memory so is almost certainly not correct but just to give you an idea.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe a simple Replace would work.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\data.txt")
strSearchString = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strSearchString = Replace(strSearchString,"A,B,C,D","A,B,C,E")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\data.txt",2)
objFile.Write strSearchString
objFile.Close
```

Comment: The values `A`, `B`, `C`, ... were just samples. Furthermore the old answer should do the job fine.