# Target users in login script from an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

So currently our logon script is targeting by users to perform tasks.

```
'Add in each user in quotes and a comma between after user.  See below...Keep usernames LOWERCASE.  Make sure end 

Select Case LCase(strUserName)
Case "user1", "user2", "user3",

    DeleteShortCut "VPN.lnk"
    DeleteShortCut "RequestIT.lnk"
    DeleteShortCut "Microsoft Outlook 2010.lnk"
    PinToTaskBar "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office", "Microsoft Word 2010.lnk", "DELETE"
    PinToTaskBar "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office", "Microsoft PowerPoint 2010.lnk", "DELETE"
    PinToTaskBar "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office", "Microsoft Excel 2010.lnk", "DELETE"
    PinToTaskBar "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office 2013", "Word 2013.lnk", "DELETE"
    PinToTaskBar "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office 2013", "PowerPoint 2013.lnk", "DELETE"
```

I want to target a list of users from CSV to send them a message. The names of the users are dynamic and will change often that's why I can't target them by AD group. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I was trying something with file system object earlier but couldn't get it to work at all.

Comment: CSV is a simple text file with delimiters. Just read and parse it. I. e. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093550/reading-a-csv-file-using-vbscript